# If $f$ is continuous and differentiable, and $f'(x)$ $\ge$ $1$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $f'(x)\ge1$, then $$\int_a^b f(x)dx \ge \left(f(a)+{b-a \over 2}\right)(b-a)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Use the Mean Value Theorem to show that $f(x)\ge f(a)+(x-a)$ when $x\ge a$.

Therefore $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \ge \int_a^b (f(a)+x-a)\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

It is primarily the same as the other answer: $\displaystyle \int_{a}^b f(x) dx = \displaystyle \int_{a}^b \left[f(a) +\displaystyle \int_{a}^x f'(t)dt\right]dx \geq \displaystyle \int_{a}^b (f(a) + 1(x-a))dx = f(a)(b-a) + \frac{(b-a)^2}{2}$.